# Difference between mysql rows

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that's something like this:

```
date               product ID    sold
-----              ----------    ----
2013-04-20 09:00   ABC           10
2013-04-20 09:00   DEF           15
2013-04-20 09:00   HIJ           15
2013-04-20 10:00   ABC           5
2013-04-20 10:00   DEF           10
2013-04-20 10:00   HIJ           20
and so on..
```

I'd like to get the difference between the amount each product sold for every hour, sorted by the descending difference, so the result for the above would be:

```
2013-04-20 10:00   HIJ           5
2013-04-20 10:00   ABC           -5
2013-04-20 10:00   DEF           -5
```

I've tried a few things, like joining the table with itself, but I can't get it right. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: can you show us your work please?

Comment: The question is a little unclear as to what you're trying to do. In your projected result, should HIJ not be 5? Since it sold 20 at 10:00 and 15 at 09:00? Also, if I'm understanding this correctly; do you just want to show the difference in sales between the row's hour and the preceding hour for each product?

Comment: Yes, you're right - sorry about that. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT t.date, t.productID, t.sold-tp.sold
FROM (
  SELECT t1.date, t1.productID, t1.sold, MAX(t2.date) date_prec
  FROM
    yourtable t1 INNER JOIN yourtable t2
    ON t1.productID=t2.productID AND t1.date>t2.date
  GROUP BY
    t1.date, t1.productID, t1.sold) t INNER JOIN yourtable tp
  ON t.productID=tp.productID and t.date_prec=tp.date
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3edbfa/1).

In the subquery I'm joining yourtable with itself, on the same product ID and with the condition that `t1.date>t2.date`. Grouping by t1.date, productID and sold you can get the previous datetime, which is `MAX(t2.date)`. I'm then joining this subquery with yourtable again, in order to get the value of `sold` of the previous day.

**EDIT**

You might also want to use this:

```
SELECT t.date, t.productID, t.sold-tp.sold
FROM
  yourtable t INNER JOIN yourtable tp
  ON t.productID = tp.productID
     AND t.date = tp.date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

here I'm returning the difference between `sold` and `sold` of the previous hour.

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3edbfa/4).

Comment: He needs `tp.sold-t.sold`. You change teh query for this

Comment: Does this not assume that there is only one "last row" per hour per product? The data would have to have totals for each hour already in the table for this to work as intended, yes?

Comment: @jesse_galley yes, not sure if it is correct, but I'm assuming that the OP wants to get the difference of sold and the previous sold. If some hours are missing, or if some hours have more than one row per each productID the result could be not correct

Comment: That works, thanks. I actually forgot one more thing - what if I wanted the result for a specific date/hour?

Comment: @Kint you can add the condition `WHERE t.date = '2013-04-20 10:00'` to return the difference between the sold of 10:00 and 09:00 (second query) or the difference between the sold of 10:00 and the sold of the previous datetime

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing something like this:  SELECT t1.date, t1.productID, t2.sold-t1.sold as sold_diff
  FROM
    yourtable t1 INNER JOIN yourtable t2
    ON t1.productID=t2.productID AND t1.date='2013-04-20 10:00' AND t2.date='2013-04-20 11:00' order by sold_diff desc

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't work when there are multiple sales per hour ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2631f6/2/0 ) or if the sales don't happen exactly on the hour ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e64d5/1/0 )

Comment: @RossSmithII i can't be sure, but i believe that data is grouped already by hour, if it is my query should give the correct result

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with temporary tables. First summarize your data via:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_summary
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    sold INT NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    NULL AS id,
    product_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') date,
    SUM(sold) AS sold
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    product_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
ORDER BY
    1,2;
```

From that summary table, you can create your report:

```
SELECT
    b.product_id,
    a.date AS prev_hour,
    b.date AS this_hour,
    b.sold - a.sold AS diff_sold,
    a.sold AS prev_sold,
    b.sold AS this_sold
FROM
    sales_summary a
INNER JOIN
    sales_summary b ON b.id = a.id + 1 AND b.product_id = a.product_id 
ORDER BY
    a.product_id,
    a.date DESC;
```

which returns:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| product_id | prev_hour           | this_hour           | diff_sold | prev_sold | this_sold |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ABC        | 2013-04-20 10:00:00 | 2013-04-20 11:00:00 |        40 |        10 |        50 |
| ABC        | 2013-04-20 09:00:00 | 2013-04-20 10:00:00 |       -10 |        20 |        10 |
| DEF        | 2013-04-20 09:00:00 | 2013-04-20 10:00:00 |       -10 |        30 |        20 |
| HIJ        | 2013-04-20 09:00:00 | 2013-04-20 10:00:00 |        10 |        30 |        40 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

A working example is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/897d9/1/0

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply with a correlated subquery, although it might not be as efficient on large tables:

```
select `date`, `productId`, ifnull(sold-(
  select sold
  from sales i
  where i.date < s.date
  and i.productId = s.productId
  limit 1
), sold) as diff
from sales s;
```

One caveat: That query, and the others in the other answers rely on one thing: the data in the table already being grouped by hour, which will not be the case in most scenarios.

Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3780c2/1).

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't work if the sales don't happen exactly on the hour (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3df18/2/0)

Comment: Technically, yes it does, it just labels the whole hour as the first occurrence in that hour. That can be easily fixed by wrapping the timestamp in the select statement with hour(time()). Keep in mind that this answer is the only one that doesn't assume that all the data is already arranged by hour. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3df18/3

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not right, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d98f5/1 uses the same input data, and has the correct values (ABC/11am is 40, not 30).

Comment: You're correct, I didn't notice that. I've removed the incorrect query until I've time to fix it.